# Spring Cloud Contract: Multiple controllers

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-contract

I've a spring cloud contract base test class:

```
public abstract class TestsBase {

    @Autowired
    protected MyFirstController myFirstController;
    ...

    RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(myFirstController);
}
```

This class is referenced in my maven plugin config as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud-contract.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <basePackageForTests>com.contracts.basepackage</basePackageForTests>
      <baseClassForTests>com.contracts.basepackage.TestsBase</baseClassForTests>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

I need to add a second controller, `MySecondController` to this setup. Just adding

```
RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(mySecondController);
```

does NOT work. Any idea how I can achieve this? I haven't been able to find a solution anywhere yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`standaloneSetup` takes varargs. Just pass the second controller next to the first one: `RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(myFirstController, mySecondController);`

Comment: Thank you very much, @Marcin. I feel stupid for not having looked at the Javadoc first :(

Comment: What if my controllers have package private visibility?

Comment: then you either do the 1) base class mappings and you have a base class per controller 2) you just need to use the web app context version of rest assured's MockMvc 3) perform a hack: you'll need to have an accessor in a package (e.g. `a.b.c`) in tests that would be public (`public class MyPackageScopeControllerAccessor { }`) that would have a public method to access package scope `public MyPackageScopeController controller() { return new MyPackageScopeController();}`